# Azure Spring Boot ZipException

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, tomcat, azure-web-app-service

I've got a spring boot rest service with embedded tomcat deployed on an Azure App Service and I am experiencing intermittent outages, every few weeks.

Every time there is an outage the logs contain the following entries:

> Message:  java.util.zip.ZipException: ZIP_Read: error reading zip file ZIP_Read: error reading zip file
>   Exception type:   java.util.zip.ZipException
>   Failed method: java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400

With the following call stack.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:
   at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarWarResourceSet.getArchiveEntries (JarWarResourceSet.java133)
   at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource (AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java256)
   at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal (StandardRoot.java281)
   at org.apache.catalina.webresources.CachedResource.validateResource (CachedResource.java97)
   at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource (Cache.java69)
   at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource (StandardRoot.java216)
   at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource (StandardRoot.java206)
   at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.internalMapWrapper (Mapper.java1027)
   at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.internalMap (Mapper.java842)
   at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.map (Mapper.java698)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest (CoyoteAdapter.java679)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service (CoyoteAdapter.java336)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service (Http11Processor.java803)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process (AbstractProcessorLight.java66)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process (AbstractProtocol.java868)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun (NioEndpoint.java1459)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run (SocketProcessorBase.java49)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java1149)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java624)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run (TaskThread.java61)
   at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java748)
Inner exception java.util.zip.ZipException handled at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarWarResourceSet.getArchiveEntries:
   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400 (ZipFile.java60)
   at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read (ZipFile.java734)
   at java.io.FilterInputStream.read (FilterInputStream.java133)
   at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read (PushbackInputStream.java186)
   at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readFully (ZipInputStream.java403)
   at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readLOC (ZipInputStream.java278)
   at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry (ZipInputStream.java122)
   at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init> (JarInputStream.java83)
   at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init> (JarInputStream.java62)
   at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatJarInputStream.<init> (TomcatJarInputStream.java37)
   at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarWarResourceSet.getArchiveEntries (JarWarResourceSet.java108)
   at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource (AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java256)
   at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal (StandardRoot.java281)
   at org.apache.catalina.webresources.CachedResource.validateResource (CachedResource.java97)
   at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource (Cache.java69)
   at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource (StandardRoot.java216)
   at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource (StandardRoot.java206)
   at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.internalMapWrapper (Mapper.java1027)
   at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.internalMap (Mapper.java842)
   at org.apache.catalina.mapper.Mapper.map (Mapper.java698)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest (CoyoteAdapter.java679)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service (CoyoteAdapter.java336)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service (Http11Processor.java803)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process (AbstractProcessorLight.java66)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process (AbstractProtocol.java868)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun (NioEndpoint.java1459)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run (SocketProcessorBase.java49)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java1149)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java624)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run (TaskThread.java61)
   at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java748)
```

As soon as this occurs, all calls to the rest service returns a 500 and the log gets another entry like above. This continues until I manually reboot the app service.

I'm struggling to figure out what is the issue. Googling the exception only returns results for issues with opening zip files. The app does not do any zipping/unzipping in itself and the call stack seems to indicate that it's tomcat things(that could be caused by something I've done on Azure, in SpringBoot, the JVM or something else entirely).

CPU or memory usage appear to be fine preceding the outages so that doesn't seem to be a factor. 
This issue is not preceded by any deployments or platform changes.

I'm stumped regarding what to do next, if anyone can point me in the right direction to investigate, it'll be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using `always on` feature for the webapp ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#general-settings

Comment: Yes, I have always on switched on.